# Can i have a javascript onclick code that will automatically play an audio presented in my blogger post

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, blogger, buttonclick

I am new to Stackoverflow and I don't know how to use it, and I own a music website that is hosted on a blogger platform. And I am getting 2000 users per day. I want some change in my blogger website and that is mentioned below-

I have a music download website and I want to put a onclick code in my blogger suggested posts, I have an audio link in my blogger post and user can play it, and after a post, there is a related song widget and if you click on that you will land on next page but instead of this, I want another code in which user can check/listen to songs before landing (means the user can play audio without landing on music post if user like that then he can open that post by clicking on the title)

Blogger theme I am using- https://pureapk-templatemark.blogspot.com/

actually, I customized it and I have replaced apk icons with my audio play logo, that exactly looks like a audio play button.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXEFo.png)

```html
<b:if cond='data:post.firstImageUrl'>
<a expr:content='data:post.firstImageUrl'/>
    </b:if>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
        <a expr:href='data:post.url'><img alt='thumbnail' class='post-thumbnail' expr:src='data:post.thumbnailUrl'/></a>
    <b:else/>
        <a expr:href='data:post.url'><img alt='thumbnail' class='post-thumbnail' src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-rsiOlyJJZaQ/X8Y4UsO3A7I/AAAAAAAAEls/iAopwPTiKpAClMiGXQQ99vqtH-MPSZWKACLcBGAsYHQ/s72-w58-c-h58/play_icon%2B%25281%2529.png'/></a>
    </b:if>
    </b:if> 
    </b:if>
<div class='data-info'>
  

    <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
            <h2 class='post-title entry-title'>
<b:if cond='data:post.link'>
<a expr:href='data:post.link' expr:title='data:post.title'>
<data:post.title/>
</a>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:post.url'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:post.url'>
<a expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title'>
<data:post.title/>
</a>
<b:else/>
<data:post.title/>
</b:if>
<b:else/>
<data:post.title/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
</h2>
<b:else/>
<h1 class='post-title entry-title'>
<b:if cond='data:post.link'>
<a expr:href='data:post.link' expr:title='data:post.title'>
<data:post.title/>
</a>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:post.url'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:post.url'>
<a expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title'>
<data:post.title/>
</a>
<b:else/>
<data:post.title/>
</b:if>
<b:else/>
<data:post.title/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
</h1>
</b:if>
<b:else/>
<h1 class='post-title entry-title'>
<b:if cond='data:post.link'>
<a expr:href='data:post.link' expr:title='data:post.title'>
<data:post.title/>
</a>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:post.url'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:post.url'>
<a expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title'>
<data:post.title/>
</a>
<b:else/>
<data:post.title/>
</b:if>
<b:else/>
<data:post.title/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
</h1>
</b:if>
</b:if>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
<div class='post-info'>
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
<span class='label-info'> 
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<a expr:href='data:label.url + &quot;?max-results=9&quot;' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a><b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'/>
</b:loop>
</span>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:top.showTimestamp'>
<b:if cond='data:post.url'>
<span class='time-info'>
<a class='timestamp-link' expr:href='data:post.url' rel='bookmark' title='permanent link'><abbr class='published updated' expr:title='data:post.timestampISO8601'><data:post.timestamp/></abbr></a>
          </span>
        </b:if>
        </b:if>

<div class='recent-com'><a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;' expr:title='data:post.title'><i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-download'/> Download</a></div>
    </div>
  </b:if>
    </b:if>
  
  

    </div>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
      <div class='post-body entry-content' expr:id='&quot;post-body-&quot; + data:post.id'>
        <data:post.body/>
        <div style='clear:both;'/> 
      </div>
    <b:else/>
    </b:if>
    
    <b:else/>
```

Comment: Adding a link to your Blogger Website would help analyse the page and recommend answers to your questions. i.e., Sending your Website's Link helps to identify the way audio is to be played, its source, etc.

Comment: Site link- http://mixringtone.com/